# Synchronising my PDA with three or more PC's

Tags: activesync

Simple problem: I have a PDA/Smartphone which I want to keep synchronized with my Outlook at home and Outlook at work. No problem there, since ActiveSync allows two different PC's.

But now I want to use a third PC, a laptop which I can use when on holidays, and ActiveSync chokes! It can only handle two PC's, so I need to delete an existing connection to add a new one. *I hate that!*

Well, is there any way to bypass this restriction?

Comment: You're lucky!  I can't even get my Windows Mobile setup to remember *a single* association with my smart phone, let alone two! http://blog.dynasphere.ca/2008/10/i-do-not-endorse-purchase-of-treo-750.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it's time to get a hosted MS Exchange account.  Connect all the computers to that via Outlook and let the smartphone sync directly to it.  Getting a smartphone to sync to multiple machines can be quite the problem.  I had a lot of issues with conflicts and duplicated items when I tried to do it without Exchange.